# Extending volume controls on volume change in Windows 10 (similar to Spotify on Windows)

Tags: c#, windows, media, spotify, volume

I'm new to C# and programming applications on Windows.

My goal is to achieve an effect similar to the Spotify application as seen [here](https://images.app.goo.gl/Ar9brMYTvMEYYW2H8). More specifically, when the volume changes or a volume key is pressed I want to display a window with configurable UI elements.

After playing around with Spotify it seems as though the application is hooking into a Windows library to customize the volume display. I believe this because it reacts to mouse over events in a similar way to the volume controls (ex, mousing over spotify overlay will keep the volume overlay visible and vise-a-versa).

What would the high level approach be to achieving this type of UI element in Windows 10 (I don't care about other devices)? My current approach involves triggering a `Form` display when a system volume change occurs.

Comment: The magic search phrase is "system media transport controls".

Comment: Can you elaborate? Looking at this, the SMTC libraries seem to revolve around events pertaining to which media is playing (new audio/video, pause, resume, etc...) and apply to a specific media source.

The use case I'm interested in is agnostic of a media source (system volume is what I care about) and is triggered based on volume, not changes to the underlying playback media.

Comment: You can provide information to the SMTC and respond to events from it. Your original description made it sound like that's what you wanted to do: Put your app's info in the SMTC like Spotify does. But I guess that's not what you want?